# Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller

Tags: ros2, gazebo-ros2-control

I am using gazebo_ros2_control to simulate a prismatic joint. ROS distro - iron. Using gazebo Classic 11.

URDF relevant to the prismatic joint-

```
<!--ELEVATOR CAR-->

<joint name="elevatorCar_joint" type="prismatic">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="0.0" upper="1" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="elevatorCar"/>
</joint>

<link name="elevatorCar">
    <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.3"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1.32 1.1 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.3"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="1.32 1.1 0.02"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:inertial_box mass="100" x="1.32" y="1.1" z="0.02">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.3" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_box>
</link>

<gazebo reference="elevatorCar">
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
</gazebo>

<!-- GAZEBO CONTROL FOR THE ELEVATOR-->
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="elevatorCar_joint">
        <command_interface name="position">
            <param name="min">-10</param>
            <param name="max">10</param>
        </command_interface>
        <state_interface name="position">
            <param name="initial_value">1.0</param>
        </state_interface>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="effort"/>
    </joint>
</ros2_control>

<gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
        <parameters>$(find bot_elevator)/config/elevator_controller.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

yaml file -

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    joint_trajectory_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

joint_trajectory_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - elevatorCar_joint
    interface_name: position
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
```

Launch file -

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():

    package_name='bot_elevator'

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true'}.items()
    )

    # Include the Gazebo launch file, provided by the gazebo_ros package
    gazebo = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'), 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')]),
             )

    # Run the spawner node from the gazebo_ros package. The entity name doesn't really matter if you only have a single robot.
    spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description',
                                   '-entity', 'my_bot'],
                        output='screen')

    # load_joint_state_controller = ExecuteProcess(
    #     cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
    #          'joint_state_broadcaster'],
    #     output='screen'
    # )

    # load_joint_trajectory_controller = ExecuteProcess(
    #     cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
    #          'joint_trajectory_controller'],
    #     output='screen'
    # )

    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        # RegisterEventHandler(
        #     event_handler=OnProcessExit(
        #         target_action=spawn_entity,
        #         on_exit=[load_joint_state_controller],
        #     )
        # ),
        # RegisterEventHandler(
        #     event_handler=OnProcessExit(
        #         target_action=load_joint_state_controller,
        #         on_exit=[load_joint_trajectory_controller],
        #     )
        # ),
        rsp,
        gazebo,
        spawn_entity,
    ])
```

I tried with and without loading controller. First manually after the world, spawn initiation because it was one of the recommended solution I found online. Then I tried including it in the launch file but both methods did not work.
Output of the Launch file with the error -

```
[ros2-5] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-5]: process has died [pid 5844, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_state_broadcaster'].
[INFO] [ros2-6]: process started with pid [5965]
[ros2-6] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-6]: process has died [pid 5965, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_trajectory_controller'].
```

Comment: Resolved it. If your package is in your custom workspace, you need to source the files from the gazebo_ros2_control workspace to load the control_manager

Comment: Please post the solution as an actual answer and **not** in the comments. Also please take the [tour] to better understand how Stack Exchange works.